# MySQL Workbench: TypeError when migrating from SQL Anywhere to MySQL

Tags: mysql-workbench, sqlanywhere

I'm attempting to migrate some data from a SQL Anywhere 16 database into MySQL to get the data into a workable format. I'm following [this tutorial](http://mysqlworkbench.org/2013/06/how-to-database-migration-from-sybase-sqlanywhere-using-mysql-workbench/)

In the middle of the migration I encounter the following error. `Reverse engineer selected schemas` failes with the following log message:

```
Starting...    
Connect to source DBMS...    
- Connecting...    
Connect to source DBMS done    
Reverse engineer selected schemas....    
Reverse engineering [dbname] from [dbname]    
- Reverse engineering catalog information    
Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\modules\db_sqlanywhere_re_grt.py", line 489, in reverseEngineer    
    return SQLAnywhereReverseEngineering.reverseEngineer(connection, catalog_name, schemata_list, context)    
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\modules\db_sqlanywhere_re_grt.py", line 169, in reverseEngineer    
    catalog = super(SQLAnywhereReverseEngineering, cls).reverseEngineer(connection, '', schemata_list, context)    
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\modules\db_generic_re_grt.py", line 237, in reverseEngineer    
    catalog = cls.reverseEngineerCatalog(connection, catalog_name)    
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\modules\db_generic_re_grt.py", line 388, in reverseEngineerCatalog    
    cls.reverseEngineerUserDatatypes(connection, catalog)    
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\modules\db_sqlanywhere_re_grt.py", line 41, in wrapped_method    
    res = method(cls, connection, *args)    
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\modules\db_sqlanywhere_re_grt.py", line 192, in reverseEngineerUserDatatypes    
    if cls.serverVersion().majorNumber < 12:    
    TypeError: serverVersion() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)    

Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\workbench\wizard_progress_page_widget.py", line 192, in thread_work    
    self.func()    
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\modules\migration_schema_selection.py", line 175, in task_reveng    
    self.main.plan.migrationSource.reverseEngineer()    
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\modules\migration.py", line 369, in reverseEngineer    
    self.state.sourceCatalog = self._rev_eng_module.reverseEngineer(self.connection, self.selectedCatalogName, self.selectedSchemataNames, self.state.applicationData)    
    SystemError: TypeError("serverVersion() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)"): error calling Python module function DbSQLAnywhereRE.reverseEngineer    
ERROR: Reverse engineer selected schemas: TypeError("serverVersion() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)"): error calling Python module function DbSQLAnywhereRE.reverseEngineer    
Failed
```

This seems to be an error with the Python module itself, so I'm at a complete loss as to how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you have found a bug in migration wizard. Please fill bug report at http://bugs.mysql.com. In the meantime you can workaround this issue by open file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\modules\db_sqlanywhere_re_grt.py in text editor, go to line 192 and change line:
if cls.serverVersion().majorNumber < 12:
to
if cls.serverVersion(connection).majorNumber < 12:
Then save file and run migration wizard again. Be careful with editing, this is python file so every space in idention have matter.

Comment: Did you file a bug report?

Comment: @PhilipOlson Yup, I filled.